# Image of connected set is connected implies continuity?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f\colon \mathbb{R} \mapsto   \mathbb{R}$ be a function with the property that the image of every connected set is connected. Is $f$ necessarily continuous?

I've recently learned the definition of connected set and i'm still not totally confortable with it. I thought about the function $f(x)=\sin(1/x)$ for all real non zero $x$ and $f(0)=0$ (obviously discontinuous) for a counterexample but i'm not certain that the image of every connected set is connected...

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: The standard counterexample ;) What are the connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Are the connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ the intervals?

Comment: Precisely those. Open, half-open, closed, degenerate (both endpoints the same), one or both ends may be infinite. Now, outside $0$, the function is continuous, so all intervals that don't contain $0$ have connected image. It remains to investigate the intervals containing $0$.

Comment: There are more interesting examples as well, for instance, you can have a noncontinuous function so that the image of every open nonempty interval is the entire ${\mathbb R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Recall the theorem that says

> A subset $E$ of the real line $\mathbb{R}$ is connected if and only if
>   it has the following property: If $x\in E, y\in E$ and $x<z<y$, then
>   $z\in E$.

So your question reduces to does every function satisfying the following property: let $x,y$ be such that $f(x)<f(y)$ then there exists a $c\in (x,y)$ such that $f(x)<f(c)<f(y)$ ([Darboux property](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Darboux_property)) is continuous? This has already been answered [Continuity $\Rightarrow$ Intermediate Value Property. Why is the opposite not true?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/622076/continuity-rightarrow-intermediate-value-property-why-is-the-opposite-not-tr) (noticed by [Andred Caicedo](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/462/andres-caicedo))